# Implementation of Queues using Linked lists

Tags: c++

The queue is implemented using linked list: but the program isn't working, what could be the possible mistake?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};


class queue
{
    node *front, *rear;
public:
    queue()
    {
        front=rear=NULL;
    }
    void insert_in_queue();
    void delete_in_queue();
    void display_queue();
};

void queue:: insert_in_queue()
{
    node *ptr;
    ptr= new node;
    cout<<"\nInsert element\n";
    cin>>ptr->data;

    if(rear==NULL)
        front=rear=ptr;
    else
    {   rear->next=ptr;
        rear=ptr;
    }
}

void queue:: delete_in_queue()
{
    node *ptr;
    ptr=front;
    if(rear==NULL)
        cout<<"\nUnderflow!!\n";
    else if(front==rear)
        front=rear=NULL;
    else
        front=front->next;
    cout<<"\nThe deleted element is:: "<<ptr->data<<"\n";
    delete ptr;
}

void queue:: display_queue()
{
    node *ptr;
    ptr=front;
    cout<<"\nThe queue is:\n";
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"|"<<ptr->data<<"|";
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}

void main()
{
    queue q;
    char ch;
    int a;
    ch='y';
    cout<<"this is dynamic que progream\n\n\n";
    do
    {
        cout<<"(1)->Insert / (2)->Delete\n";
        cin>>a;
        if(a==1)
            q.insert_in_queue();
        else
            q.delete_in_queue();
        q.display_queue();
        cout<<"\nContinue?(y/n)\n";
        cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='y');

    cout<<"\nThe final queue is:\n";
    q.display_queue();
    system("pause");

}
```

The console screen just disappears after entering the first element, I can't figure out where is the mistake.

Comment: Use a [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to find out what went wrong.

Comment: the dibugger runs the program but the program stops during execution. how to proceed?

Comment: ***how to proceed?*** You step through the code line by line with your debugger looking at your variables at each step until your code does something that you did not expect.

Comment: somehow i couldn't figure out that's why i asked here

Comment: The rear node's `next` pointer should always be null.

Comment: so what should i change?

Comment: ***what should i change?*** Your `insert_in_queue()` to properly initialize `node` after you allocate it or add a constructor for `node` that sets next to nullptr.

Comment: @drescherjm success :) adding     ptr->next=NULL; inside function     insert_in_queue()   solved the issue. thnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `insert_in_queue()` function, after allocating memory for `ptr`, make sure to use

```
ptr->next=NULL;
```

Comment: In addition, consider adding a constructor to `node` that always nulls `next` so you can't forget.